# How do I pass a function for background worker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want to create a function so everytime I can pass the function to call when I need run the function in backgroundWorker. like this.

```
void RunInBackgroundWorker(Func<object, DoWorkEventArgs, bool> do_work)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += do_work;
    worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

But visual studio complain that it cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func' to 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler'

Is that possible to do it in this way? How to correctly pass the function in?

Comment: you should be using async await instead of BackgroundWorker

Comment: `worker.DoWork += (s, e) => e.Result = do_work(s, e);`. But BackgroundWorker is outdated. Use async/await.

Answer (score 2):

```
worker.DoWork += (s, e) => do_work(s, e);
```

Also this has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: async await would be the WPF way

Comment: Or tasks, or manual threads, or anything that wasn't tailor made for .NET 1.1 15 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it. Instead of passing a funtion (Func do_work), I pass (DoWorkEventHandler do_work) and it works!